# handling OK click with multiple sumo select instaces

Tags: jquery

How do I identify the instance of my list for which OK button was clicked if I am using sumo select with 2 list boxes in same page.

Below is my complete code: 
Below is my complete code:

```
<script 
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="jquery.sumoselect.min.js"></script>
<link href="sumoselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$(<%=ListBox1.ClientID%>).SumoSelect({ selectAll: true, okCancelInMulti: 
true });
$(<%=ListBox2.ClientID%>).SumoSelect({ selectAll: true, okCancelInMulti: 
true });

$('.btnOk').on('click', function ()
{
  alert('OK button Clicked');    });
});
</script>    

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>

<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lstBoxTest1" SelectionMode="Multiple">
 <asp:ListItem Text="Red" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="Green" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="Yellow" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="Blue" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="Black" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:ListBox>

<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lstBoxTest2" SelectionMode="Multiple">
<asp:ListItem Text="Merc" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Audi" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Jaguar" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Porsche" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Toyota " Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>

</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show us the `form` code?

Comment: Added complete code above

Comment: Use this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55255277/multiple-sumo-select-ok-click-events

Answer (score 0):

> OK button fires 'change' event if triggerChangeCombined:true and
>   selection changed.

```
$(<%=lstBoxTest2.ClientID%>).SumoSelect({ selectAll: true, okCancelInMulti:true,triggerChangeCombined:true }); $(<%=lstBoxTest2.ClientID%>).on('change',function(e){ alert('OK button Clicked'); });
```

---