# multiple Sumo select Ok click events

Tags: jquery, sumoselect.js

How do I make sure that the Sumo select Ok click event is different for different selects.

Similar unanswered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43561364/handling-ok-click-with-multiple-sumo-select-instaces)

This is I have tried in jsfiddle but can't get it work.

https://jsfiddle.net/dew3nmja/

```
<select id="island" multiple>
    <option value="Big Island">Big Island</option>
    <option value="Oahu">Oahu</option>
    <option value="Kauai">Kauai</option>
    <option value="Maui">Maui</option>
</select>
<select id="island2" multiple>
    <option value="Big Island2">Big Island2</option>
    <option value="Oahu2">Oahu2</option>
    <option value="Kauai2">Kauai2</option>
    <option value="Maui2">Maui2</option>
</select>

/// I get these classes from Developer tools and tried to iterate through it but no luck.

$('#island').next(" .MultiControls .btnOk").click( function () {
       alert('okk');
 });

 $('#island2').next(" .MultiControls .btnOk").click( function () {
       alert('222');
 });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `#island ~ .optWrapper .MultiControls .btnOk`

```
$("#island ~ .optWrapper .MultiControls .btnOk").click( function () {
   alert('okk');
});
```

if you look at `#island` then the next object that contains your `.btnOk` is `.optWrapper`